# FlexUnitApplication.html and FlexUnitApplication.swf not generated

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, flex4, flexunit4

**Context**

I have

- a **project Flex-Java** in Eclipse Indigo service Release 2, (a web application)
- and i use the plugin Flash-builder to work on it.
- I use sdk 4.5.1

**What i try to do**

1) I try to make a simple test case with FlexUnit4. When i create a new Test Case) : New > Test Case Class, Eclipse by Default create :

- package flexUnitTests + with my new Test case : (for example :
  TestDoc.as)
- package byDefault with one file : FlexUnitCompilerApplication.mxml
- a html a swf file for FlexUnitCompilerApplication is auto-generated in bin-debug folder.

Till this point all seems to be good, so I try to execute the unit test :

2) I want to execute the unit test :

- A FlexUnitApplication.mxml is created in the default package

**The problem** :

**The compilator doesn't generate the files : FlexUnitApplication.hmtl and FlexUnitApplication.swf in bin-debug folder...**

And there is an error written in the "error screen" :

- description Impossible to resolve all the ressources "FlexUnitTestRunner"
- place or Localisation : Unknown

  *sorry i try to translate the description  from a French version*

**Other informations**

I succeeded doing this in other projects... the FlexUnitApplication files are auto-generated.

**Question(s)**

It seems that, it is bound with something in this particular project. Maybe something is hindering the process to autogenerate these files ?? I cannot figure it out why??

Is it Possible to force the compilator doing these files (html and swf) ??

I am really lost.. and i tried things, i looked in the properties, in the metadata's ... i really don't understand.

Somebody maybe has an idea for that, what could i do, what could i check ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I always have troubles with unit tests in eclips+FB plugin as well.

After the FlexUnitApplication.mxml is created goto your project settings and update the following:

- remove the dynamic {locale} compiler flag and add a specific '-locale=en_US' only.
- if you have custom locale files add those to the source path manually
- in the library path find the entry that points to the dynamic locale library '..sdk/../{locale} and copy the path. click on add SWC to library path. Paste the copied path and replace '{locale}' with 'en_US'

Generally this turns out favorable for me.

Comment: Ok ! I thought about the difference with the "local settings" in the compiler arguments. And actually in this project, i have these options for the compilation : _-locale=nl_BE,fr_BE -source-path=locale/{locale}_...  I have to check this....   I had decided not to use the plugin for the FlexUnit.. and to add manually *.swc. .. But i will check this...